# Sinch authencation using own backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sinch

I am able to generate the token for users and successfully start the SinchClient by following this [tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/authenticating-sinch-rails-devise/). Now, next step is to send and receive messages. Now, how do I recognize users? Since I am using authentication token to start the SinchCleint and not a particular username when starting a SincClient, then how can I send messages to a particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you recognize Sinch doesn't have the info about your users, you only start the client with a unique token. Sinch is built on the assumption that you have a user database and social network of you own, and the sinch client "address" to send messages to is something you keep track of. Does that make sense?